# Best way to access variable in different class android

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android. Many time I need to access variable from different class without creating object like accessing variable from MainAvtivity. I find two ways to pass variable to different class one way is create object in main activity and pass variable in constructor second way is make variable as public static and access it from second class. Which one is a best way and way ?

**UPDATE**

MainAvtivity:

```
 Public static EditText editText;
 onCreate(){
    // other code
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 }
```

OtherClass

```
// accessing editText
editText.setText("Some text");
```

**Other way to achieve this**

MainActivity:

```
 onCreate(){
    // other code
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    new OtherClass(editText);
 }
```

OtherClass

```
 EditText editText;
 OtherClass(EditText et){
    editText = et;
 }

 // other code
 editText.setText("Some text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entirely depends on the actual classes themselves.

Activity -> Activity = `Intent` (which is really a wrapper around a `Bundle`)

Activity -> Fragment = `Bundle`

(`Parcelable` and `Serializable` classes are most helpful for those.)

Activity / Fragment -> something else = Probably a constructor, but again. Depends

---

Need global variables? `SharedPreferences` or `SQLiteDatabase`.

`public static` shouldn't be used for much other than `final String` or `final int` **constants**.

You can make an `Application` class, yes, but that should not be heavily relied on for a singleton pattern.

---

If you really want something more complex than that, look into interfaces and [an EventBus library](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/).

Model-View-Presenter is a good design to follow for designing proper interfaces between the UI and your data.

**EDIT**

```
public class OtherClass { // Presenter

    private Model mData; // Model

    public interface OnTextChangeListener {
        void onTextChanged(String text); // Callback to View
    }

    public Model getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    OnTextChangeListener listener; // Callback to View

    // other code
    mData.setName("some other string"); // Update the model
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onTextChanged(mData.getName()); // Present the data
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity  // Presenter
    implements OtherClass.OnTextChangeListener {

    private EditText editText

    @Override
    void onTextChanged(String text) {
        editText.setText(text); // Present the data
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // Other code...

        // Bind the Presenter to the View
        OtherClass x = new OtherClass();
        x.listener = this; // 'this' being the *interface*, not the Activity
    }

}
```

Comment: But sometime variable are not simple. Some variable you can only define in Activity like accessing TextView etc. I think you can't save it in `SharedPreference` or `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: You should never store a View globally. You can store a String wherever, then in `onCreate` of that one Activity, you load the `TextView`

Comment: If variable is View and second class is not extended from Activity then what is the best way to access it from second class.

Comment: Like I said, passing any type of `View` class is a bad idea. Especially making them `static`.

Comment: @PakDeveloper Please see update with an example how not to pass around an `EditText`

Comment: I want it for every View. If it's a `listView` not a `TextView`. And `OtherClass` is an adapter class then How can I access `ListView` in `OtherClass`

Comment: What about passing view in constructor ? And why static is Bad idea ?

Comment: An adapter should never know about what ListView contains it. That is the whole idea of the "adapter pattern" in object-oriented programming. And `static` is bad because if you don't have **constants** you are abusing that keyword and global variables are pointless in a good application design (my opinion)

Comment: If you have a ListView + Adapter, you pass an `ArrayList<Model>`. Never the View itself. Where `Model` contains Java variables of `String`, `int`, etc. and no `View`'s either.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use a comman global class which can hold the variables. You can use the getter setter in that class itself for the variables.

Comment: But sometime you only define variable Activity class Like accessing a TextView